# how could i find uniprot ac in blast?

Tags: blast, uniprot

I have made a search in p-blast.
I would like to search for the protein results in uniprot. how can I do it directly?
I can go to GENBANK but i would like to go to UNIPROT.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Ah ... yes thats tricky. The only thing I can suggest is using Biopython for Genbank and Uniprot because Biopython facilitates both.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

UniProt also provides a BLAST service (https://www.uniprot.org/blast), or you could use the Expasy BLAST too, at https://web.expasy.org/blast.

If you have performed your similarity search at NCBI or elsewhere, you can map the identifiers from that result to UniProt by using the UniProt IDmapping service at https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists. This can also be used programmatically, cf https://www.uniprot.org/help/api_idmapping

Comment: This is all very useful information... just want to add that [NCBI Protein BLAST](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastp&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome) also has "UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot" as a Database option.